# XPath 2.0 : Open implementations

Tags: language-agnostic, xpath, implementation

I find it very difficult to find an XPath 2.0 implementation outside of Saxon.

What are the XPath 2.0 options in other languages ?

*Note :*
[This blog post](http://bluesock.org/~willg/blog/dev/xpath-2.0.html) made an interesting summary of the situation in 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath 2.0 is a subset of XQuery 1.0 so you could look at XQuery 1.0 implementations such as

- [XQilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage)
- [Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/)
- [MXQuery](http://mxquery.org/)
- [XmlPrime](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/index.htm)
- [AltovaXML tools](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html)

That is a list of some XQuery 1.0 and/or XPath 2.0 implementations, but not necessarily open source ones.

Comment: One down: "We are sorry, Qizx has been discontinued."

Answer (score 0):

XQSharp includes both XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0.

Comment: this is in the accepted answer with links. Please do not duplicate answers.